# Не проставляется time.Time

Tags: golang, дата, model, struct

Есть структура:

```
type Add_rows struct {
Id        int64
Fam       string
Name      string
Lastname  string
Datebirth string
Phone     string
Homeadres string
Numberud  string
Lgotcat   string
Fiovrach       string
DateInvitation string
DateNar        string
Numbernar      string
Fioreg         string
Comment        string
NumberNar      string
DateOpenNar    //Какой тип данных?
DateCloseNar   time.Time //если указываю его то в базу записывается "0001-01-01"
}
```

Есть функция которая принимает запрос из формы:

```
func AddNar(rnd render.Render, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("idNar"), 0, 64)

    dateOpenNar, _ := time.Parse("MM/DD/YYYY", r.FormValue("dateOpenNar"))
    dateCloseNar, _ := time.Parse("MM/DD/YYYY", r.FormValue("dateCloseNar"))
    row := models.Add_rows{
        Id:           i,
        NumberNar:    r.FormValue("numberNar"),
        DateOpenNar:  dateOpenNar,
        DateCloseNar: dateCloseNar,
    }
}
```

Не могу разобраться какой тип данных нужно указывать в структуре, для того что-бы в базу попадала только дата переданная с формы.

Comment: Что в Вашем случае попадает в структуру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде сразу несколько ошибок. Во-первых, вы не проверяете ошибки. Во-вторых, вы неверно используете `time.Parse`; для того чтобы распарсить такой формат, форматную строку надо указывать так:

```
const layout = "01/02/2006"
dateOpenNar, err := time.Parse(layout, r.FormValue("dateOpenNar"))
// errcheck
dateCloseNar, err := time.Parse(layout, r.FormValue("dateCloseNar"))
// errcheck
```

[Читайте документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Из-за того, что вы не проверяли ошибки и использовали неверный формат, время у вас нулевое.

А единственный тип даты и времени в го - это `time.Time`.

Comment: пытаю сделать так как написано выше 

https://play.golang.org/p/guPt-LGHdv 

такой формат приходи с формы formDateOpenNar := "0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC2017-03-04"

Comment: все разобрался.